# Get all routes that start with rt_

Tags: php, array, iterator, laravel

The code reads all my routes and return to my AJAX request the names of the routes without duplicates and just those that have the "rt_" prefix.

```
class RouteController extends Controller {
    public function getRoutes()
    {
        
        //Get all the routes.
        $routes = Route::getRoutes();

        
        //Setting up the vars
        $array = [''];

        
        
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $condicional = substr($route->getName(), 0, 3);
            $found = FALSE;

           //Filtering the routes with rt_ prefix
            if ($condicional == 'rt_') {

                 //Filering duplicates
                foreach ($array as $item) {
                    if ($item == $route->getName()) {
                        $found = TRUE;


                    }

                }

                
                //Echo without duplicates
                if ($found == FALSE) {
                    $array[] = $route->getName();

                }
            }
        }

        return response()->json($array, 200);

    }


}
```

Comment: You can do `array_unique` at the end. No need for extra loop at every matched route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to simplify this would be to create a collection with `collect()` and then call `getName()` on each route using [`Collection::map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map). Then use [`collection::filter()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter) to filter out the routes that don't start with `rt_` using the string helper method [`Str::startsWith()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-starts-with)

```
class RouteController extends Controller {
    public function getRoutes()
    { 
        // call getName on each route and then get unique values
        $uniqueRoutes = collect(Route::getRoutes())
            ->map(fn($route) => $route->getName())
            ->unique(); 
        //filter out any routes not starting with rt_
        $filteredRoutes = $uniqueRoutes->filter(function($name) {
             return Str::startsWith($name, 'rt_');
        });
        return response()->json($filteredRoutes, 200); 
    }
}
```

<sub>Note - the uses the PHP 7.4 [arrow function syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) could be used to simplify the callback to the `filter()` method</sub>

One could also use [`collection::reduce()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reduce) to only add routes to the list that contain the desired prefix.

---

The existing code contains this block:

> ```
>           //Filering duplicates
>            foreach ($array as $item) {
>                if ($item == $route->getName()) {
>                    $found = TRUE;
>                }
>            }
> ```

That could be simplified using the PHP function [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array).

---

Another suggestion is to always use strict equality comparisons (i.e. `===` and `!==`) when possible - e.g. when `$found` should either be `true` or `false` then compare without the possibility of type conversion (i.e. with `==`).

Comment: Thanks for your help! My IDE it's giving error in `fn()` asking to change PHP version in composer.json to 7.4 but it's working fine.